# What is "structured investment"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does it mean "**arranged** investment"?

Another senior SoftBank executive told the FT that the deal was inspired by Warren Buffett, the so-called Oracle of Omaha. Buffett has a history of using structured investments to drive returns.

Source: https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/stocks/wirecard-softbank-trade-executives-lose-hundreds-millions-warren-buffett-inspired-2020-6-1029334594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structured investments usually
combine a debt security with exposure linked to the performance of
an underlying asset, such as equities,
interest rates, commodities or currencies. In some instances, exposure can be
linked to two or more underlying assets,
which are often referred to as hybrid
offerings or derivative investments.
Structured investments are typically
originated and offered by investment
banks and come in a variety of forms,
the most common being senior unsecured notes of the issuer. They can also
come in the form of CD bank deposits,
and their principal (but not unrealized
gains) is insured up to applicable limits
by the Federal Deposit Insurance Corp.
(FDIC), an independent agency of the
U.S. government.

Refer: [Morgan Stanley](https://www.morganstanley.com/structuredinvestments/docs/marketingmaterials/Introduction_to_Structured_Investments.pdf)